# Is the solution to this integral correct

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{(x^{2}-b^{2})(x^{2}+c^{2})}dx=\pi(\frac{\cos(ab)-e^{-ac}}{b^{2}+c^{2}})$$

Where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$
I was wondering if anyone can confirm
If the above is correct, I don't need a solution just verification, note that the above is Gradshteyn and Ryzhik equation 3.728.9 but there solution is incorrect in the book of table of integrals, series and products (7th edition ) just a comment would be sufficient

Comment: Given the divergence at $x=\pm b$, is this integral meant to be taken in the principal-value sense?

Comment: I'm not too sure, it's a type 4 integral which can be evaluated using the residue theorem

Comment: i think we Need more infomations about $a,b,c$

Comment: All I have is that $a,bc $ are positive reals

Comment: Check my proof below. Anyway why did you think the result is wrong?

Comment: Because it differed to that in the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that via residues theorem we can rewrite it as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{z \Im e^{iaz}}{(z^2-b^2)(z+ic)(z-ic)}\ dz$$

A simple pole is present at $x = \pm ic$ whilst only one lies in the upper half plane whence

$$2\pi i \Im \left(\frac{z e^{iaz}}{(z^2-b^2)(z+ic)}\right)\bigg|_{z = ic}$$

Which gives

$$\color{red}{-\pi \frac{e^{-ac}}{b^2+c^2}}$$

**NOT THE END**

This is a "special" integral. It's not only made of the usual poles on the imaginary axis, but real poles along the real axis are present. Indeed we also have $x = \pm b$. Real.

In this case, residue theorem guarantees an additional term in the solution which is:

$$\pi i \text{Res }\ \left(f(x)e^{iax}\right)\bigg|_{x_k}$$

Where this time the poles are real.

By substituting $x_k = \pm b$ we get

$$\pi i \left(\frac{b e^{iab}}{(b^2+c^2)(2b)} + \frac{(-b)e^{-iab}}{(b^2+c^2)(-2b)}\right)$$

Using elementary trigonometry, arranging, we get eventually

$$i\pi \frac{e^{iab} + e^{-iab}}{2(b^2+c^2)}$$

Hence

$$i\pi \frac{\cos(ab)}{b^2+c^2}$$

Being it part of the Imaginary request part, we get the additional term

$$\pi \frac{\cos(ab)}{b^2+c^2}$$

Which summed to the previous term gives really

$$\color{blue}{\pi\left(\frac{\cos(ab) - e^{-ac}}{b^2+c^2}\right)}$$

**THIS MEANS THE ABOVE SOLUTION IS CORRECT**

Comment: Thank you. , I was just unsure if it was correct but now that's clear , thank you  , if you could remove your working that would be great as I only needed verification, but I do appreciate it also may I ask why the above solution doesn't apply if $b=0$ or $c=0$?

Comment: If $b = 0$ then there would be a real pole at $x = 0$ (double) which would transform $\cos(ab)$ into $\cos(0) = 1$ and the $b^2$ term into $0$. If $c = 0$ this wouldn't be solvable by residues anymore because no complex poles would arise, hence it shall become either a principal value or it would diverge.
If both $b = c = 0$ then you would have 

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^3}\ dx$$

Which would diverge.

Comment: How would you test for divergence of the integral ?

Comment: @Gibberish An integration by parts is more than sufficient to show the divergence!

Comment: I've never came across the idea of an integral diverging, is there anything online that could explain this ?

Comment: @Gibberish Start with this reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral